# Get Javascript objects by class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo

Dojo for instance adds a member to a JS object called "declared_class". I would like to find those and replace some stuff. And, can this be done also outside of Dojo ? I know, JS is not type oriented but you never know whats out to bypass this lack of introspection facilities.

Update : This is NOT about DOM objects. I am writing a sort of real-time Javascript editor. After I reloaded the script, I need to locate related (Dojo modules) objects and mixin altered functions only.

Update 2 : It doesn't seem to be possible without a prototype or a similar patch. Since all the code is running 1:1 in a node instance as well, I am wondering whether I can determine those objecys in a node.js instance ?

Comment: All global objects should be properties of the `window` object. You could do a `for...in` over `window`, test `if ("declared_class" in Prop)`, then do whatever you want.

Comment: That is assuming that `declared_class` is enumerable.

Comment: Sure, if they are in global. But that's not the case at all, I am afraid.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible, unless you save all those objects in a cache on their initialisation - with access to this list you caould update them afterwards even without prototypical inheritance. Of course this would be a memory-leaking strategy

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I was afraid to do that in this way too.